# Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tridion.broker.querying.Query

Tags: classnotfoundexception, tridion

I am trying to contact tridion content broker database to get published contents using Tridion.contentDelivery dll.  When i tried executing the application i am getting the below exception.

Please help

```
    Exception Details: Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tridion.broker.querying.Query

Source Error: 


Line 107:
Line 108:            LoggerService.Debug("GetContentByUrl: about to create query", LoggingCategory.Performance);
Line 109:            Query pageQuery = new Query();
Line 110:            LoggerService.Debug("GetContentByUrl: created query", LoggingCategory.Performance);
Line 111:            ItemTypeCriteria isPage = new ItemTypeCriteria(64);  // TODO There must be an enum of these somewhere


Source File: C:\MyProjects\DD4T\dotnet\DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2011sp1\TridionPageProvider.cs    Line: 109 

Stack Trace: 


[ClassNotFoundException: com.tridion.broker.querying.Query]
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.NTypeValue.Throw(Int64 inst) +574
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst) +1361
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.init() +390
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.get_JObject() +51
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.init() +1652
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.get_MethodPtr() +61
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.get_Handle() +80
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallObject(JavaProxy jpo) +493
   Com.Tridion.Broker.Querying.Query..ctor() +57
   Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.Query.Query..ctor() +32
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Review the jar files that are located in the lib folder of your application.

There should be a cd_broker.jar there.

You can review that following these [installation instructions (for .NET)](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_3E3A2FB1B4E34C20934B5A841C2E0930).